# After integration firebase + gtm ,events is not shown in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I followed this link - https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5/.
I can see my events in firebase console but not in google analytics.I defined my custom as well as default apple logevents.As it is also coming in my console "[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023024] No data to upload. Upload task will not be scheduled". I am using xcode 8.3.2 and swift3.Please help if anyone implemented.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few issues that can cause this. And more information is needed to find the cause, best place to look is the debug console in xCode.

1. GTM container is not setup correctly.
2. GTM Tags are not setup correctly.
3. The App/SDK checks for newer versions of the GTM container in 12 hour intervals. So if you did run the app for testing with a container with no tags, then added the tags to test for GA input, then the new container will not be used, until it gets the new container 12 or so hours later. (Work around for me was to uninstall the app from the simulator and run it again in xCode, just to be safe I clean the code too before running again. I did read somewhere that there was code to always check for newer containers, but I never got that to work)

Would be good if you can provide more information from the xCode debug console.